# Is the value returned by refaddr permanent?

Tags: perl, perlguts

According to [Scalar::Util's documentation](https://metacpan.org/pod/Scalar::Util#refaddr), `refaddr` works like this:

> ```
> my $addr = refaddr( $ref );
> ```
>
> If $ref is reference the internal memory address of the referenced value is returned as a plain integer. Otherwise undef is returned.

However, this doesn't tell me if `$addr` is permanent. Could the `refaddr` of a reference change over time? In C, for example, running `realloc` could change the location of something stored in dynamic memory. Is this analogous for Perl 5?

I'm asking because I want to make an [inside-out object](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlobj.html#Inside-Out-objects), and I'm wondering whether `refaddr($object)` would make a good key. It seems simplest when programming in XS, for example.

Comment: `$ref` is variable and thus subject to change, however it references to something (object?), and location of object should be permanent (as long it doesn't get recycled by going out of scope).

Comment: [Class::InsideOut](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Class::InsideOut)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First of all, don't reinvent the wheel; use [Class::InsideOut](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Class::InsideOut).

---

It is permanent. It must be, or the following would fail:

```
my $x;
my $r = \$x;
... Do something with $x ...
say $$r;
```

Scalars have a "head" at a fixed location. If the SV needs an upgrade (e.g. to hold a string), it's a second memory block known as the "body" that will change. The string buffer is yet a third memory block.

[image: Layout of an SVt_PVIV scalar]

```
$ perl -MDevel::Peek -MScalar::Util=refaddr -E'
   my $x=4;
   my $r=\$x;
   say sprintf "refaddr=0x%x", refaddr($r);
   Dump($$r);
   say "";

   say "Upgrade SV:";
   $x='abc';
   say sprintf "refaddr=0x%x", refaddr($r);
   Dump($$r);
   say "";

   say "Increase PV size:";
   $x="x"x20;
   say sprintf "refaddr=0x%x", refaddr($r);
   Dump($$r);
'
```

```
refaddr=0x2e1db58
SV = IV(0x2e1db48) at 0x2e1db58             <-- SVt_IV variables can't hold strings.
  REFCNT = 2
  FLAGS = (PADMY,IOK,pIOK)
  IV = 4

Upgrade SV:
refaddr=0x2e1db58
SV = PVIV(0x2e18b40) at 0x2e1db58           <-- Scalar upgrade to SVt_PVIV.
  REFCNT = 2                                    New body at new address,
  FLAGS = (PADMY,POK,IsCOW,pPOK)                but head still at same address.
  IV = 4
  PV = 0x2e86f20 "abc"\0                    <-- The scalar now has a string buffer.
  CUR = 3
  LEN = 10
  COW_REFCNT = 1

Increase PV size:
refaddr=0x2e1db58
SV = PVIV(0x2e18b40) at 0x2e1db58
  REFCNT = 2
  FLAGS = (PADMY,POK,pPOK)
  IV = 4
  PV = 0x2e5d7b0 "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"\0   <-- Changing the address of the string buffer
  REFCNT = 2                                    doesn't change anything else.
  CUR = 20
  LEN = 22
```